# How to fade in individual letters of text on iOS

Tags: ios, animation, text, uilabel

What's the best way to fade in individual letters of a UILabel over time? I'm looking to create something similar to the example below.

http://s11.postimg.org/5s16qmwn5/secret.gif

Comment: probably each letter is in a isolated `UILabel` and it faded one-by-one; or the `CoreGraphics.framework` used with dynamic texting; or `QuartzCore.framework` used with dynamic masking... there are many ways to implement such simple text effect. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to go with since I didn't want to over-complicate it if there was an easy method I wasn't thinking of. I'm not too familiar with CATextLayers and was thinking that using a mask might be the easiest method.

Comment: the custom visual effects are usually clever imaginations and ideas only, not overcomplicated ones. the experience level of the developer defines which is the most clever solution for making a specific effect. it s not htoo gelful, and probably I won't be popular with my opinion (no offence at all!) but it is true and generic rule: if you need to ask _ideas_ from someone else about making a task, that task is probably over your level of experience. there are many possible solution are here for achieveing such an visual effect, and no one can tell you which idea fits for you. :(

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `UILabel` to do this.

I would create a `UIView` with `CATextLayers` inside it, one text layer for each character. Then you can animate the text layers independently.

Check out apple's WWDC videos on core animation to learn how it works. It's very simple.

Comment: Can you please refer me the link for the wwdc video which helps me to learn CATextLayer animation

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `NSAttributedText` to create your own `UITextView` or `UILabel` that does that, basically randomly assigning `UIColors`  with decreasing Alpha to different letters,

It will take a while to find the correct speed and rate of change. Open source it then :)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to have each letter go from alpha 0 to 1, but I haven't figured out how to make it fade in using NSAttributedText.